# How to change text size in actionbar dropdown list - with Actionbar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to change the font size in a drop down list that uses Actionbar Sherlock 4.0.

I see from [https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/401] that you can change the Actionbar tab text size using a theme as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyTabText</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.MyTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTabText" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

But I've not been able to find how to change the text size in a drop down list (i.e., both the header, and the individual drop down list items).

Any clues?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the spinner items larger when click on it you can use this code :

```
    String[] objects = { "Tehran", "Shiraz",
            "Esfehan" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> ap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            objects);

    sp.setAdapter(ap);
```

but if you want to increase font of text in spinner you must use custom arrayadapter, use this link for more information and set textSize of textView for see spinner items larger : [Spinner ArrayAdapter crashing with custom layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5267808/1105277)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using the ABS design pattern, which has spinner strings defined in an XML file, so I'm not quite sure how to use your idea.  I'm trying to solve it with a themes.xml file as follows (doesn't work):<resources>
    <style name="GCTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDown</item>        
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDown</item>
     </style>
     
    <style name="MyDropDown" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
     <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
      </style>
</resources>

Comment: email your project to solve it, i don't know what is ABS Design. a.shariat.b@gmail.com

Comment: ABS = Actionbar Sherlock.  I've taken care of it, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I didn't end up using it.

Comment: hi @gcl1, have you got any solutions? I came across the same problem.

Comment: @Bolton: I'm sorry to say that my design changed, and it turns out I don't need to change the font size any more.  Good luck, and please let us know if you solve it!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the source of Actionbar Sherlock, the theme of the spiner text uses spinnerItemStyle/actionDropDownStyle but changing that get no effect
However, it works to define your custom layout in the spinerAdapter like below :

```
    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            context, R.array.orderstatus, R.layout.spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

where the layout file like:

```
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```